# Error on ALTER TABLE command on MariaDB 10.3? How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was asked to associate DEPARTMENT's Mgrssn to EMPLOYEE's Ssn and add a foreign key constraint by using the ALTER TABLE command. I have tried these commands:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (Mgrssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn);

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (Mgrssn) REFERENCES 'EMPLOYEE'('Ssn');

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (Mgrssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE('Ssn');
```

and i keep getting an error

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`company`.`#sql-124c_a`, CONSTRAINT
>   `#sql-124c_a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Mgrssn`) REFERENCES `employee`
>   (`Ssn`)).

I dont know what to do anymore, Im relatively new to mysql. I would appreciate it if anyone could help. Thank you

Comment: You probably have rows in department, column mgrssn that doesn't exists in table employee, column ssn.

Comment: your last two attempts are wrong. Error is pretty clear that you have some rows in the child table where foreign key `mgrssn` value does not exist in the `ssn` column of employee table.

Comment: You should review the conditions required https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Your last two query attempts to apply Foreign Key are wrong, and should throw syntax errors, or give unintended behaviour.

Following attempt is correct:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (Mgrssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn);
```

Now, the error basically states that there are some row(s) in the chid table `DEPARTMENT` where value of the column `Mgrssn` does not exist in the column `Ssn` of the Parent table `EMPLOYEE`.

You can identify those rows utilizing `LEFT JOIN`. Try the following:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.* 
FROM DEPARTMENT 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.Ssn = DEPARTMENT.Mgrssn 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.Ssn IS NULL
```

You will now need to fix those rows in the `DEPARTMENT` table. You can either change those `Mgrssn` values in the `DEPARTMENT` table; **OR** Remove those rows; **OR** add those missing `Mgrssn` values in the `Ssn` column of the `EMPLOYEE` table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add column with foreign key, because in DEPARTMENT table there exists rows which no exists in EMPLOYEE with Ssn value.

Explanation:

DEPARTMENT Mgrssn has value for example 100 that no exists in EMPLOYEE with Ssn 100.

Yo can do two things:

1. Remove records from DEPARTMENT with Mgrssn values that no exists in EMPLOYEE Ssn
2. Add all missed values to the EMPLYEE with Mgrssn that no exists in EMPLOYEE Ssn